# Separate a single column containing varying numbers of responses into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a column which reports the results of a question in a survey where respondents could tick as many or as few of seven pre-determined responses as they wished, and additionally could input their own free text response. Currently the responses are all stored in one column, with each selected and/or typed response separated by a semicolon. I would like to separate these into eight columns: the seven possible checkboxes and one for the free text response.

A small reprex to show what I'm aiming for (fewer columns than my real data but the basic idea is the same):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# where `fruit` is the input data
fruit <- tibble(id = 1:5,
                fruit = c('apple;banana',
                          'apple',
                          NA,
                          'banana;a free response which isn\'t any of the other columns',
                          'banana;apple;orange')
                )
fruit
#>      id fruit                                                      
#>   <int> <chr>                                                      
#> 1     1 apple;banana                                               
#> 2     2 apple                                                      
#> 3     3 NA                                                         
#> 4     4 banana;a free response which isn't any of the other columns
#> 5     5 banana;apple;orange     

# the output I'm trying to get:
tibble(id = 1:5,
       fruit = c('apple;banana','apple',NA,'banana','banana;apple;orange'),
       apple = c(T,T,F,F,T),
       banana = c(T,F,F,T,T),
       orange = c(F,F,F,F,T),
       other = c(F,F,F,'a free response which isn\'t any of the other columns',F))

#>      id fruit               apple banana orange other                                               
#>   <int> <chr>               <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <chr>                                               
#> 1     1 apple;banana        TRUE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE                                               
#> 2     2 apple               TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE                                               
#> 3     3 NA                  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE                                               
#> 4     4 banana              FALSE TRUE   FALSE  a free response which isn't any of the other columns
#> 5     5 banana;apple;orange TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
```

I've tried various things, including the `tidyr::separate()` function and various permutations of `tidyr::pivot_wider()`, but haven't been able to get particularly close to the desired result. All the approaches I've looked at so far expect the column to be split to have the same number of responses in each cell (and in the same order), but this is not the case in my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use [`mtabulate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdapTools/versions/1.3.5/topics/mtabulate).

1. Split the 'fruit' column at `;` with `strsplit` into a `list`
2. Replace the elements that are not `apple`, `banana`, `orange` or not a missing value to 'other'
3. Apply `mtabulate` to get the frequency of the elements across the `list`, `cbind` after converting the count to logical (`> 0`)

```
library(qdapTools)
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(fruit$fruit, ";"), function(x) 
      replace(x, (! x %in% c("apple", "banana", "orange")) & !is.na(x), "other"))

cbind(fruit, mtabulate(lst1) > 0)
```

-output

```
 id                                                       fruit apple banana orange other
1  1                                                apple;banana  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE FALSE
2  2                                                       apple  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE
3  3                                                        <NA> FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE
4  4 banana;a free response which isn't any of the other columns FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
5  5                                         banana;apple;orange  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Split the 'fruit' rows with [`separate_rows`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/1.1.3/topics/separate_rows)
2. Create a new column ('fruit1'), by replacing the elements that are not 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' to 'other' within [`case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when)
3. Reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html).  Specify the `values_fn` as a lambda function to change those elements in 'fruit' that are not 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' to the corresponding value or else return a logical (converted to `character`).
4. Use `type.convert` to automatically change the column types
5. Join with original data - `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
fruit %>% 
    separate_rows(fruit, sep = ";") %>% 
    mutate(fruit1 = case_when(fruit  %in% c("apple", "banana", "orange") ~ fruit,  
     is.na(fruit) ~ NA_character_,
         TRUE ~ "other")) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = fruit1, values_from = fruit, 
      values_fn = function(x) ifelse(! x %in% 
       c("apple", "banana", "orange"), x, as.character(length(x) > 0)),
       values_fill = "FALSE") %>% 
    select(-`NA`) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
    left_join(fruit)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     id apple banana other                                                orange fruit                                                      
  <int> <lgl> <lgl>  <chr>                                                <lgl>  <chr>                                                      
1     1 TRUE  TRUE   FALSE                                                FALSE  apple;banana                                               
2     2 TRUE  FALSE  FALSE                                                FALSE  apple                                                      
3     3 FALSE FALSE  FALSE                                                FALSE  <NA>                                                       
4     4 FALSE TRUE   a free response which isn't any of the other columns FALSE  banana;a free response which isn't any of the other columns
5     5 TRUE  TRUE   FALSE                                                TRUE   banana;apple;orange
```

Comment: These are really helpful, thanks! This achieves 90% of what I wanted, but if you have any ideas on how to get the free text response into the 'other' column when other == TRUE, then that would also be really helpful!

Comment: @MatthewLaw then, it will change the column type to character

Comment: I'd ideally like an `other` column with a character column type and which is is empty when other == FALSE but shows the response when not, or an additional `response` column showing the same thing